# Why can't I read comments in Area 51?

Tags: bug, comments, area-51

Two of my questions ([1](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/113814/medical-sciences/114253#114253), [2](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/113814/medical-sciences/114256#114256)) have several hidden comments, but clicking to show them only show the typing box, not the newest comments. This happens on my phone (Android, Firefox) and PC (Windows, Firefox). I've flagged on there but no-one replies.

Comment: There are no moderators on Area 51, only one single [SE employee](https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/5/robert-cartaino) who can't possibly be expected to handle all the flags. Maybe he does, but won't be surprised if it takes weeks for a custom flag to be handled.